# Почему символы не отображаются?

Tags: c++

Кто объяснит мне, почему символы не отображаются, а вместо них непонятный символ один выводится? Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Stack {
  private:
    int maxSize, top;
    char *stack_array;

  public:
     Stack(char n) {
        stack_array = new char[n];
         maxSize = n;
         top = 0;
    } ~Stack() {
        delete[]stack_array;
    }

    void push(char a) {
        if (top >= maxSize) {
            cout << "Stack is FULL!";
        } else
            stack_array[top++] = a;
    }

    int pop() {
        if (top == 0) {
            cout << "Stack is EMPTY!";
        } else
            return stack_array[--top];
    }

    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < top; i++) {
            cout << stack_array[i] << " ";
        }
    }

    char show(char a) {
        return stack_array[a - 1];
    }
};

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    char massiv[20];
    int k = 0;

    string str = "1 + 2";

    for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
        if (str[j] != '+' && str[j] != '-' && str[j] != '*' && str[j] != '/') {
            massiv[k] = str[j];
            cout << "\n" << j << ") код=" << (int) massiv[k] << "  = " << massiv[k];
            k++;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Вот скрин]

Comment: massiv[k++] = str[j];
    cout << massiv[k++];
объясни на словах что тут происходит, и поймешь причину :)

Comment: ну каждому последовательному элементу массива присваивается значение str[j] @vv2cc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот код, который выведет код символа и его значение.

```
int main()
{
    std::system("chcp 1251");
    char massiv[20];
    int k = 0;

    std::string str = "1 + 2";

    for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
        if (str[j] != '+' && str[j] != '-' && str[j] != '*' && str[j] != '/') {
            massiv[k] = str[j];
            cout << "\n" << j << ") код=" << (int) massiv[k] << "  = " << massiv[k];
            k++;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: то же самое выводит =/

Comment: Он должен вывести вот это

    0) код=49  = 1

    1) код=32  =

    3) код=32  =

    4) код=50  = 2

Comment: не выводит. Те же самые значки выходят

Comment: покажите что именно выводится.
Код точно такой включаете?

Comment: обновил код @manking

Comment: в cin что попадает?
1+2?  Или буквы?

Comment: 1) если вы поставите  std::string str = "1 + 2"; без cin? то тогда работает?

2) Из cin что попадает в строку? Выполните код и покажите что он выдает.
    std::system("chcp 1251");
    std::string str;
    cin >> str;
    
    cout << "\nstr=" << str;
    for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) 
    {
    cout << "\n" << j << ") код=" << (int)str[j] << "  = " << str[j];
    }

Comment: @navi1893, у вас k обнуляется? Если нет, то не удивительно что на экран выводится мусор.

Comment: @insolor т.е обнуляется? А зачем обнулять?

Comment: @navi1893, про какой код (сейчас в Вашем вопросе **только кусочек**) речь идет.

Вы бы всю программу выложили.

Comment: @navi1893 чтобы быть точно уверенным, замени строку на: for(int j = 0, k = 0; j < str.length(); j++)

Answer (score 2):

```
 > massiv[k++] = str[j];
 > cout << massiv[k++];
 k++
```

Comment: то же самое выводится @istem

Comment: У тебя инкремент идёт, два раза. Попробуй откомпилировать в уме, или на листочке - поймёшь.

Comment: а какая разница сколько раз идет? там же каракуля влетает. Моя проблема в этом

Comment: В таком случае, рекомендую задать этот вопрос на сайте govnokod.ru

Comment: @navi1893, вы прибавляете к k 2 раза единицу. Присвоение идет четным элементам массива, а выводите вы нечетные, притом не иницализированные.

Comment: @istem ты там админ?

@Yura Ivanov, спасибо! Но как каляки убрать? Чтобы правильно выводился ответ?

Answer (score 1):

Лично меня смущает вот эта строка:

```
std::system("chcp 1251");
```

Попробуйте заменить ее на:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

Comment: а ещё лучше #include <locale.h> и в майне setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus")

но я всё же считаю идеальным вариант www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/ruscpp/ всё таки и ввод и вывод

Comment: @avp только и пишу этот же код на линуксе и на строку: for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) выдает ошибку: предупреждение: сравнение знакового и беззнакового целых выражений. Зачем?

@Mirdin тут цифры я ввожу. Русский язык тут не причем

Comment: @navi1893
я же вам сказал, покажите какие коды символов у вас выводятся.
Если те же, то возможна проблема со шрифтами.

Comment: @navi1893, как Вам это (предупреждение) получить удается???

У меня

    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ cat t2.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int 
    main ()
    {
      string s = "1 + 2";
    
      for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
        cout << s[j] << '\n';
      return 0;
    }
    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ g++ t2.cpp 
    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
    1
     
    +
     
    2
    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ 

все работает.

Чего-то Вы недоговариваете...

Comment: @avp вот выложил весь код. Этот код выдает верхние ошибки. Компилирую на Code::Blocks

Comment: уберите system из кода.
Замените на unsigned int j в цикле.

Comment: @manking Вывод: 49 = 1, 32 = пусто, 32 = пусто, 50 = 2

Comment: Сработало. Но в чем была проблема? Я все еще не понял =/

Comment: Где именно? У вас несколько раз код менялся. Я сам запутался, с чего всё началось.

Вроде бы Yura Ivanov сказал в чём проблема. И самые первые комментарии об этом.

    // здесь massiv[0]==undefined
    // здесь massiv[1]=='1'
    massiv[k++] = str[j]; 
    
    // здесь запрашивается massiv[2] который ==undefined
    cout << massiv[k++];

Comment: @navi1893, **Вы уникум.**

Я просто копипастнул Ваш код и g++ (в винде MinGW (**никаких IDE!!!**)) собрал его. Я его запустил и увидел 

    0) код=49  = 1
    1) код=32  =  
    3) код=32  =  
    4) код=50  = 2

Т.е. работает?

В линуксе, ну пришлось добавить \#include <stdlib.h>

и тоже все отобразилось (вместе с руганью, что нет команд chcp и pause).

--

Мой Вам совет: начните заново, с Си (без крестов)(с HelloWorld), в Linux (в винду ни ногой) и без всяких IDE. Только текстовый редактор, gcc и немного погодя make.

Через полгода ежедневного решения задачек из K&R Вы себя не узнаете.

Comment: @avp, почему именно в линуксе? почему "в винду ни ногой" ?
аргументируйте пожалуйста

Comment: Еще можно тестирование пройти.

certifications.ru

quizful.net

intuit.ru


несколько раз сдать тест по Си и Си++ записать результаты.

Потом почитать книгу по Си, по создавать мини программки пару недель

И снова пойти попробовать сдать. Посмотреть изменения. Потом повторять по кругу.

Comment: @ProkletyPirat, очень просто и коротко. Unix сделан группой очень толковых программистов **для себя**, а винда для зарабатывния денег на ней и **продажи** программ **для нее**.

Comment: @avp, на мой взгляд это не аргумент потому повторяю свой вопрос.
почему именно в линуксе? почему "в винду ни ногой" ? аргументируйте пожалуйста

Comment: Я не @avp, но ответить могу: чтобы уменьшить количество одновременно решаемых Вами проблем. Сначала разберитесь с Си, а уже потом с Си под виндами.

@avp Но вот фраза "Unix сделан группой очень толковых программистов для себя" -- настораживает. Вы про который Unix пишете? (Тем более, что linux -- это вообще-то не unix, да *bsd строго говоря не совсем unix, ибо не содержит кода с древних манускриптов Western Electric)

Comment: Ну, вот, чтобы сделать комментарий пришлось удалить один предыдущий. 

    Причем здесь русские буквы? Он вводит 1+2, а печатаются зюки.
    
    И вообще, учиться программировать лучше в линуксе.


Видимо это поведение *никогда не будет изменено*. Печально....

@alexlz, все группы были **очень** хороши. Лично я не стремлюсь к "чистоте расы" и не вижу большого смысла в делении \*nix-подобных на unix/не-unix. Стремятся все примерно к одному: все есть файл, система состоит из *простых* блоков и клея, ядро содержит минимум функций.

--

@ProkletyPirat, места тут уже нет, можете начать новую тему